# SOAP Envelope XSD - https://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ does not point to the latest version

Tags: soap, envelope, envelope-schema

Does anyone know why https://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ does not point to the latest version of the envelope XSD? It appears the latest version is actually http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/2004-01-21.xsd.

My reason for asking is because I am getting schema validation errors for xml:lang when validating against http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/, but not when I use http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/2004-01-21.xsd. Should I use something other than http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ to ensure I'm always validating against the latest version?